# магические методы __iter__ и __next__

Tags: python

Почему в магических методах `__iter__` и `__next__` используется оператор return, a не yield?

Comment: Не очень понятно, зачем в них вдруг понадобился yield. Вы понимаете, чем yield отличается от return?

Comment: Недавно вопрос такой был. Функция с yield создает новый итератор, у которого внутри свои `__iter__` и `__next__`. yield - это синтаксический сахар, позволяющий простым образом создавать итератор, не объявляя целый класс, а `__iter__` и `__next__` - более низкоуровневые примитивы.